# Slicing a multi-index pandas dataframe with a large list

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, slice

I have a large dataframe with multi-index. I wanted to slice this dataframe using a fairly large list. Below is a sample code. It is taking almost 10 seconds for this operation.

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "x": np.repeat(np.arange(10000), 50),
        "y": np.repeat(np.arange(50), 10000),
        "val": np.random.rand(50*10000)
    }
).set_index(["x", "y"])

large_list = range(5000,10000)

slice = df.loc[(large_list, slice(None)),:] # Takes 10 seconds on my machine
```

As a comparison, if I write this dataframe to an hdf file and read it with a `where` condition same as my slicing operation, it takes only 1.5 seconds!

```py
df.to_hdf("sample.hdf", key="df", append=True)
df1 = pd.read_hdf("sample.hdf", "df", where='x in large_list')
```

Is there a faster way to slice in memory?

Comment: df.loc[5000:10000] works fine as well, with significant speedup. Does it meet ur use case?

Comment: No, I basically want to pass in an `iter` object rather than the `slice` itself. It could be a list with random items.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your intention is slicing multiindex by an arbitrary list, using `query` will be much faster

Create an arbitrary list from `5000` to `10000`

```
np.random.seed(0)
large_list =  np.random.choice(list(range(5000, 10000)), 5000, replace=False)

In [2245]: large_list
Out[2245]: array([5398, 8833, 9836, ..., 6653, 7607, 7732])

x = df.query('x in @large_list')
```

Compare result

```
In [2246]: y = df.loc[(large_list, slice(None)),:]
In [2249]: np.allclose(x, y)
Out[2249]: True
```

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted. Thanks a lot for introducing `query` to me!!

Comment: @najeem: Glad I could help. Happy coding :)